Animating flex property with reanimated
So im trying to implement a simple animation where i click on one container and the rest gets flex: 0 while the clicked one keeps the flex : 1
this is the code i have right now. But for some reason it doesnt work as expected.
When i click first container what happens is that the element will try to "expand" over the full screen but then it vanishes and i can see only second and third container on the screen.
What is wrong here?
import { ImageBackground, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  Easing,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import humanBg from "./assets/human_bg.jpg";
import orcBg from "./assets/orc_bg.jpg";
import nightElfBg from "./assets/nightElf_bg.jpg";
import undeadBg from "./assets/test.jpg";
import humanEmblem from "./assets/human_emblem.png";
import orcEmblem from "./assets/orc_emblem.png";
import elfEmblem from "./assets/elf_emblem.png";
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Image } from "expo-image";

export default function App() {

  const selectedRace = useSharedValue(null);


  const handleFlexStyle = (raceStr) => useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    if (selectedRace.value === null) {
      // Initial state: all containers have flex value of 1
      return { flex: withTiming(1) };
    } else if (selectedRace.value === raceStr) {
      // Selected race: expands to flex value of 1
      return { flex: withTiming(1) };
    } else {
      // Other races: collapse to flex value of 0
      return { flex: withTiming(0) };
    }
  })

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StatusBar hidden />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Animated.View style={[{
            backgroundColor: "rgba(30,47,66,.9)",
            height: "25%"
          }, handleFlexStyle("human")]}>
            <Pressable onPress={() => (selectedRace.value = "human")}>
              <ImageBackground source={humanBg} style={{ height: "100%" }} imageStyle={{ opacity: .1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", width: "100%" }}>
                  <Image source={humanEmblem} style={{ width: "50%", flex: 1 }} contentFit='contain' />
                </View>
              </ImageBackground>
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.View style={[{
            backgroundColor: "rgba(77,40,34,.9)",
            height: "25%"
          }, handleFlexStyle("orc")]}>
            <Pressable onPress={() => (selectedRace.value = "orc")}>
              <ImageBackground source={orcBg} style={{ height: "100%" }} imageStyle={{ opacity: .1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", width: "100%" }}>
                  <Image source={orcEmblem} style={{ width: "50%", flex: 1 }} contentFit='contain' />
                </View>
              </ImageBackground>
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.View style={[{
            backgroundColor: "rgba(35,90,69,.9)",
            height: "100%"
          }, handleFlexStyle("elf")]}>
            <Pressable onPress={() => (selectedRace.value = "elf")}>
              <ImageBackground source={nightElfBg} style={{ height: "100%" }} imageStyle={{ opacity: .1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", width: "100%" }}>
                  <Image source={elfEmblem} style={{ width: "50%", flex: 1 }} contentFit='contain' />
                </View>
              </ImageBackground>
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.View style={[{
            backgroundColor: "rgba(44,42,66,.9)",
            height: "25%"
          }, handleFlexStyle("undead")]}>
            <Pressable onPress={() => (selectedRace.value = "undead")}>
              <ImageBackground source={undeadBg} style={{ height: "100%" }} imageStyle={{ opacity: .1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", width: "100%" }}>
                  <Image source={elfEmblem} style={{ width: "50%", flex: 1 }} contentFit='contain' />
                </View>
              </ImageBackground>
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView >
    </React.Fragment >
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: '#282B3A',
  }
});

